# AngularFire2 - Get Single Object with db.object - Data Comes to late

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I use Angular4 (4.3.6) and AngularFire2 (4.0.0-rc.2). I get the Data for a Detail view with:

```
// GET THE ID
this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

this.subscriptions.push(
  this.db.object('/restaurants/' + this.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.restaurant = data;
    console.log(data);
  })
);
```

In this way, I get the data, but the console throw errors because the data comes a little too late. At last i dont like to get the id from route.params, because i want later use the object name as route for the detail view.

Here a StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7gabaq?file=sites/site-restaurant-detail/site-restaurant-detail.component.ts (Click on "View Restaurant")

Answer (score 0):

You can try making custom keys when creating items:
**path = `restaurants/${res_name}`**

```
newForm(res_name: string, data_1: string, data_2: string) {
const path = `restaurants/${res_name}`; // Endpoint on firebase
const userRef: AngularFireObject<any> = this.db.object(path);
const data = {
  restaurant: res_name,
  some_data: data_1,
  onether_data: data_2
};
userRef.update(data)
  .catch(error => console.log(error);
```

}